# SQL Server conditional within a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to say :

'Where the first 2 letters are not 10 and for those that do start with 10 only exclude the ones from 2018 onward'

```
where (left(c.DealCode, 2) <> '10'
    and estyear > 2018)
```

Does not work.. What am I missing ?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
where left(c.DealCode, 2) <> '10' or (left(c.DealCode, 2) = '10' and estyear > 2018)
```

or

```
where c.DealCode not like '10%' or (c.DealCode like '10%' and estyear > 2018)
```

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> 'Where the first 2 letters are not 10 **and** for those that do start
>   with 10 only exclude the ones from 2018 onward'

but what you should say:

> 'Where the first 2 letters are not 10 **or** for those that do start
>   with 10 only exclude the ones from 2018 onward'

So you must use `OR` instead of `AND` in your statement. 
Also a statement like:

```
(a doesn't start with 10) or ((a starts with 10) and (estyear > 2018))
```

is equivalent to

```
(a doesn't start with 10) or (estyear > 2018)
```

so your condition should be:

```
where c.DealCode not like '10%' or estyear > 2018
```

not sure though if

> "exclude the ones from 2018 onward"

must be `estyear > 2018` or `estyear < 2018`